# Sequelize: Tables aren't associating properly

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a trip planning application. The models I'd like to use are Users, Trips, Activities and Rentals.

This is how I intend to associate them:

A User can have many trips, activities and rentals

Many trips can have many activities and rentals

Many activities can have many rentals

[Table Associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJww0.png)

In my node server, I've created a database file with the following Sequelize associations:

```
User = sequelize.import('./models/user')
Trip = sequelize.import('./models/trip')
Activity = sequelize.import('./models/activity')
Rental = sequelize.import('./models/rental')

Activity.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Activity, { as: 'Activities' })

Rental.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Rental, { as: 'Rentals' })

Activity.belongsTo(Trip)
Trip.hasMany(Activity, { as: 'Activities' })

Rental.belongsTo(Trip)
Trip.hasMany(Rental, { as: 'Rentals' })

Rental.belongsTo(Activity)
Activity.hasMany(Rental, { as: 'Rentals' })
```

Here are my models:

user

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false
    }
})

return User;
```

}

trip

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Trip = sequelize.define('trip', {
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    departLoc: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    arrivalLoc: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    startDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    endDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    travelMethod: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    reason: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
})
return Trip;
```

}

activity

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Activity = sequelize.define('activity', {
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    startDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    endDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
})
return Activity;
```

}

rental

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Rental = sequelize.define('rental', {
    agency: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    item: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    startDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    endDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
})
return Activity;
```

}

However, when I check my pgadmin, I see that

1. My activity table has  userId, tripId, AND an unnecessary activityId column
2. My rental table DOESN'T have any associations to it.

Whenever I try inserting new entries into these models, I get errors such as the following:

[PostMan Error Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfrLB.png)

How do I associate my tables such that I get the desired associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem was in my rental model: it was returning an Activity.

All tables are now relating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize creates its own column names based on table names so when you're defining both-ways associations from source and target table give explicit names

```js
Activity.belongsTo(User, {
   foreignKey: { name: 'UserId', allowNull: false }, // column name for userId in activity table
   targetKey: 'UserId',  // column name of id in User table
});
User.hasMany(Activity, {
   foreignKey: 'UserId', // name of column in Activity table
   sourceKey: 'UserId'   // name of column in User table
})
```

Write rest of the associations like this and try.

Comment: I tried the relations your suggested and I got this error:

      throw new Error(`Unknown attribute "${this.options.targetKey}" passed as targetKey, define this attribute on model "${this.target.name}" first`);       
      ^

Error: Unknown attribute "UserId" passed as targetKey, define this attribute on model "user" first
    at new BelongsTo (C:\Users\aalan\Desktop\ElevenFiftyProjects\Projects\redbadge\tripp_it_v2\tripp_it_v2_server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\belongs-to.js:59:13)

Comment: @aamirand, `UserId` should be replaced with whatever the primary ID of `User` table is. I followed relation diagram you have added in your question.